# For loop is not working as planned

Tags: loops, for-loop

So I have been trying to get something to work for a few days here and there only putting in an hour or so of work each day.

My current code is:

```
function NewNameChange() {
  var Dashboard = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Dashboard')
  var NameChanges = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Name Changes')
  //var Number1 = 0
  var Number2 = 6
  var CellCheck = NameChanges.getRange('B' + Number2)
  var Cell1 = NameChanges.getRange('B' + Number2)
  var Cell2 = NameChanges.getRange('D' + Number2)
  var Cell3 = NameChanges.getRange('F' + Number2)
  var Cell4 = NameChanges.getRange('H' + Number2)

  for (var Number1 = 0; Number1 == 0; Number2++) {
    if (CellCheck.isBlank()) {

      Dashboard.getRange('B14').copyTo(Cell1)
      Dashboard.getRange('D14').copyTo(Cell2)
      Dashboard.getRange('F14').copyTo(Cell3)
      Dashboard.getRange('H14').copyTo(Cell4)

      Dashboard.getRange('B14').clear()
      Dashboard.getRange('D14').clear()
      Dashboard.getRange('F14').clear()
      Dashboard.getRange('H14').clear()

      Number1 = 1;
    }
  }
}
```

The goal of this code is to look at the cell B6 on the sheet named Name Changes, if this cell is empty then it goes to the sheet named Dashboard and copies the four feilds B14, D14, F14, H14, and copies this to the cells B6, D6, F6, H6, onto the Name Changes sheet. Then finally it clears the cells B14, D14, F14, and H14. Which is does wonderfully, the issue is that when the cell is not empty, because the script has been ran before and there's now data in B6, D6, F6, and H6, the script will run until timeout. When in theory it should get to the end of the for loop and had one to Number2 which then causes for the CellCheck to look at B7, although nothing ever happens.

First time on this forum and figured I would make an account to look for some help considering how helpful other answers have been. If I've used it wrong I am sorry, also if you need some further explanation please let me know!

Comment: Is this any language in particular?

Comment: Looks like you just need to debug your code and see why the value never gets set.

Comment: Not sure, I mean I am simply using the Script Editor we're given.

Comment: If this is vba or vbscript, you should say that's what it is.  (Debugging means putting breakpoints into the code and finding out what the variables are when the program stops at that point.  Do you know how to do that?)

Comment: Yea, that's what I am doing now. Simply setting the notes on a certain cell to the variable value to see what it's being set to. Currently Number2 never changes. Still working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CellCheck` thru `Cell4` are not modified inside the loop; while `Number2` was used to initialize them, changing `Number2` doesn't change those other values automatically: they have to be explicitly re-assigned to.

Comment: Thank you very much, it actually makes a lot of sense now!